# Windows 8 sound randomly changes

Tags: windows-8, audio, itunes

I've got a really strange problem. If I listen to a song, or anything on my computer, be it on iTunes or YouTube etc. at say at a volume of 20, it'll actually play at a volume of 20. As you can see:

[image]

However, if I change the volume down then back up (tried both using keyboard shortcuts and manually dragging) then the playback volume decreases by a large amount:

[image]

However, if I pause the music/video or whatever for a few seconds, or even skip to the next song (a few seconds of silence seems to do this), the volume goes back up to the original. Note that I am keeping the volume constant, but the playback volume keeps changing. I have tried several things, such as updating my sound drivers (I think this has actually made my sound quality worse btw... When I first got this laptop the sound quality was AMAZING) and setting the detect communications activity thing to 'Do nothing'. Does anyone have any ideas?!

Comment: @Karan It was happening on VLC too. That seems to have worked, but the playback volume seems to be a lot lower than usual.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click volume icon > Playback devices > Right-click Speakers > Properties > Enhancements tab > Check *Disable all sound effects* and OK your way out.

Comment: Regarding the volume being lower than before, that is probably because there was some enhancement active that was boosting the volume. You can try re-enabling the individual enhancements one by one to see if the volume can be boosted without the problem of frequent fluctuation.